# Intellij, faild to create JVM

Tags: intellij-idea, jvm

I got this error "Intellij, faild to create JVM: error code -1" when i tried to run idea64.exe.

I tried to reduce -Xmx value, reinstall and restart everything. I have java 64 bit, currently my

JAVA_HOME: c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121

I'm at my wits' end.

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNs9q.jpg)

Comment: Please post your JVM options ([.vmoptions](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544869) file) with the modifications you have performed. One of the options can be invalid.

Comment: I use the default:
`-Xms128m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=250m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow`

Comment: Try reverting to the defaults by deleting `.vmoptions` from the [config](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) folder and reinstalling IDEA from http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html.

Comment: (also try getting a download with an embedded JVM, then you don't have to)